# xcode weird method syntax definition

Tags: xcode, methods, block, declaration, definition

I inherited another developer code, but didn't understood the following code (Notice the ';' in the of first line):

```
-(id) initWithTarget:(id)target  AndAction:(void(*)(id target,id sender ,NSString* xml))action; {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setTargetAction:action];
        [self setActionDelegate:target];
    }
    return self; }
```

This code compiles fine without any warning \ error. Is it just looks to me, or this is a method declaration (which of course won't have any definition), and another block which couldn't be performed (without any method name) ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That semi-colon is simply ignored by the compiler. It's a convenience so that you can copy the method definition from the `@interface` into the `@implementation` and just get on with things. It makes no functional difference if it's there or not.

Comment: I checked it by adding semi-colon to `applicationDidFinishLaunching:WithOptions:` method, and you are right.
Thank you !